# How to find the error description from an NSError code?

Tags: ios, nserror, nsurlerrordomain

I'm trying to find an easier/more reliable way to figure out an NSError's localized description from its error code than Google searching it.

For example, I know that NSURLErrorDomain code -1003 corresponds to "A server with the specified hostname could not be found". But if I try to verify it in code it doesn't match.

```
let error = NSError(domain: "NSURLErrorDomain", code: -1003)
print(error.localizedDescription)
// "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1003.)"
```

Looking up -1003 in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorcannotfindhost) also doesn't match: "The host name for a URL couldn’t be resolved."

So I am looking for a way to figure out descriptions from an error code with a function, or the documentation that has the description I expected. I was hoping there'd be a function similar to `HTTPURLResponse.localizedString(forStatusCode:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your own `NSError` object like that, that `localizedDescription` is not generated for you. When `URLSession` generates error objects, though, the localized description is populated:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://bad.domain")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error as? URLError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)  // “A server with the specified hostname could not be found.”
    }
}.resume()
```

So, if you have an error and want to see the localized description, just do that. It simply will not work if you create your own `NSError` object manually.

But generally, we wouldn't worry about the localized description and, instead, test for various `code` values of [`URLError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror), looking for a [`code`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror/code) of [`.cannotFindHost`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror/code/2883157-cannotfindhost):

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://bad.domain")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error as? URLError {
        switch error.code {
        case .cannotFindHost: print("cannotFindHost")
        case .cancelled:      print("cancelled")
        case .badURL:         print("badURL")
        // ...
        default:              break
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Or, alternatively, you can search for the old `NSURLError` code values using `NSError`, too, looking for [`NSURLErrorCannotFindHost`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorcannotfindhost?language=objc):

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
        switch error.code {
        case NSURLErrorCannotFindHost: print("cannotFindHost")
        case NSURLErrorCancelled:      print("cancelled")
        case NSURLErrorBadURL:         print("badURL")
        // ...
        default:                       break
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

You can also “quick open” by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> (the letter “Oh”), search for `NSURLError`, uncheck the “Swift” button in the upper right corner of the quick open dialog:

[image]

When you open up the `NSURLError.h` file, you can then see all the codes listed there.

But, no, just by creating a `NSError` with the specified domain and code, the `localizedDescription` isn't magically populated for you. `URLSession` creates the proper error objects with descriptions, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no automatic lookup for most things (there is for Security errors using SecCopyErrorMessageString, but not generally). You have to check the headers. This is in NSURLError.h:

```
NSURLErrorCannotFindHost =          -1003,
```

Generally the string you're looking for will be in the NSError's userInfo, and is placed there by the thing that generates the error. It doesn't get looked up from the code. When there's no message in the userInfo, then the default for `localizedDescription` is to write "The operation couldn't be completed..."

I don't believe there's any built-in way to generate an error "like the system would have." (This would be very subsystem dependent, since URLErrors have lots of keys to fill in that don't apply to other kinds of errors.)

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I wanted to include this link for others to reference as they are trying to identify a particular Error Code number. [Error Codes provided by the Swift.org open source project on GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/NSError.swift#L1817)