# xcode datatask not running

Tags: swift5, applepay

I am new in using swift5. I am going to integrate Apple Pay with my app, however the datatask seems not working cannot see any log from the console. Can anyone tell me what I am done wrong? also how can I verify/ debug the request and response to the backend server.

```
   struct IssuerRequest: Codable{
       let certificates: [Data]
       let nonce: Data
       let nonceSignature: Data
   }


    struct IssuerResponse: Codable {
        let activationData: Data
        let ephemeralPublicKey: Data
        let encryptedPassData: Data
    }



 func execute(request: IssuerRequest, cardNumber: String, onFinish:@escaping (IssuerResponse) -> ()){
        guard let prefix = Bundle.infoPlistValue(forKey:"URL") as? String else { return }
  
    let url = URL(string: prefix + "/get/applepay")!
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(request)
        urlRequest.httpBody = jsonData
        print("req json data: \(jsonData)")
    }catch let jsonError{
        print(jsonError)
    }
    
    var issuerResponse: IssuerResponse!
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else{
            print ("Error: No Response Object")
            return
        }
        guard response.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("Error: Server response status \(response.statusCode)")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let issuerResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(IssuerResponse.self, from: data)
        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }
        onFinish(issuerResponse)
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Hope I can debug the api call

Comment: it only can print "req json data", after that there are no any further log/ error

Comment: @Rob Sorry I am very new in swift and xcode, can you give me more details to debug

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/stepping-through-code-and-inspecting-variables-to-isolate-bugs.

Comment: While [Debug with structured logging](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10226/) is focusing on some Xcode 15 debugging features, it shows an example of how to set a breakpoint and single-step through code.

Comment: FWIW, you shared an error code of `18446744073709550615`. In hex, that is `0xfffffc17`. As signed integer, `-1001`. That is [`NSURLErrorTimedOut`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrortimedout?language=objc), aka [`timedOut`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror/2293002-timedout) in Swift. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65486286/1271826 for illustration of how to decipher a `URLError.Code`. (That’s focusing on the a different error code, but the technique is the same as how I reverse engineered it here.)

Comment: Check this ```Bundle.infoPlistValue(forKey:"URL")``` line it may have returned from else block